# I'm a Sri Lankan citizen.Do I need South Korean and Malaysian transit visas?

Tags: visas, transit, paperwork, south-korea, malaysia

I'm a Sri Lankan citizen currently living in Russia. If I travel from Vladivostok to Seoul (S7 airlines) and within 24 hours from Seoul to Colombo (AirAsia with a transit in Kuala Lumpur), do I need South Korean and Malaysian visas?

Answer (score 1):

A query in TIMATIC, the database used by airport check-in staff, gives the following:

For Malaysia, assuming Seoul-Kuala Lumpur-Colombo is in a single booking, you do **not** need a transit visa if you have a South Korean visa. If you don't have one, you **do** need a transit visa.

For South Korea, assuming Vladivostok-Seoul is a separate booking, you do **not** need a transit visa if you don't have checked-in baggage. If you have checked-in baggage, you **do** need a transit visa.

**UPDATE:** Get a South Korean transit visa, and you will be 100% covered.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, Vladivostok- Seoul is a one booking  and Seoul-Kuala Lumpur- Colombo is an another one. and I will not check in bags. I'll arrive to Seoul by S7 airlines and fly from Seoul by AirAsia. Will it be a problem not having Korean visa because I use different airlines flights?

Comment: @PiumiJayasinghe The thing is, you need either a Malaysian or South Korean visa, because without a South Korean transit visa, Malaysia requires you to have a transit visa. Because many check-in agents (varies between Airports) will treat Seoul as your final destination if you have separate bookings (and thus deny boarding without a visa), even without checked luggage (partially because of connection "insurance" issues) I would strongly recommend you to go for the Korean visa